# Saving Python 3-dimensional variable size array in matlab format

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am trying to save a Python 3D int array, in which the third dimension is of variable length, in matlab format. The solution that I came up is

```
array = np.empty((FirstDim, SecondDim), dtype = object)
for i in range(FirstDim):
    for j in range(SecondDim):
        array[i][j] = ...

scipy.io.savemat('array', {'array':array})
```

But the problem is when I access the array variable in matlab, it is actually stored as just a 2D array.

```
load array.mat
array(1,1,2)
error: A(I,J,...): index to dimension 3 out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions so that I can access the array in matlab like it is a 3D array? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you save your 3D array as a 2D array of object (each object being a 1D array), Matlab loads it as a cell array, where each cell is a 1D array. You can access value in a cell array using the following syntax:

```
array{1,1}(2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem. If you were to do it, do you have other more elegant ways?

Comment: Your solution seems fine, and the most adequate imo.  Maybe if your third dimension does not vary too much in length, you could pad your array with 'NaN', you might get better compression/access speed but you would have to raise OOB errors yourself, and honestly I'm not certain there is something to gain. I'd stick with the solution you already have if I were you.